# React unit tests with Enzyme don't re-bind context of helper functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

This is an interesting issue that I came across while trying to refactor some of my React components using AirBnB's React testing library, [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme).

I think the best way to explain my problem is through an example.

Here is a small React component that will display a message depending on the props it receives from its parent component:

**test.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

function renderInnerSpan() {
    const {foo} = this.props;

    if (foo) {
        return <span>Foo is truthy!</span>;
    }

    return <span>Foo is falsy!</span>;
}

export default class extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {renderInnerSpan.call(this)}
            </div>
        );
    }    
}
```

And here is a test suite for this component with two passing tests:

**test.spec.js:**

```
import Test from '../../src/test';

import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import {expect} from 'chai';

describe('Test Suite', () => {
    let renderedElement,
        expectedProps;

    function renderComponent() {
        const componentElement = React.createElement(Test, expectedProps);

        renderedElement = shallow(componentElement);
    }

    beforeEach(() => {
        expectedProps = {
            foo: true
        };

        renderComponent();
    });

    it('should display the correct message for truthy values', () => {
        const span = renderedElement.props().children;

        expect(span.props.children).to.equal('Foo is truthy!');
    });

    it('should display the correct message for falsy values', () => {
        expectedProps.foo = false;
        renderComponent();

        const span = renderedElement.props().children;

        expect(span.props.children).to.equal('Foo is falsy!');
    });
});
```

This works fine, but the Test component's current implementation isn't as efficient as it could be.  By using `.call(this)`, it is creating a new function every time the `render()` function is called.  I could avoid this by binding the correct context of `this` in the component's constructor, like so:

```
export default class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        renderInnerSpan = renderInnerSpan.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {renderInnerSpan()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

After this change, the component still works as intended, but the tests start failing:

```
AssertionError: expected 'Foo is truthy!' to equal 'Foo is falsy!'
Expected :Foo is falsy!
Actual   :Foo is truthy!
```

I added a `console.log(props.foo)` in the constructor, which confirmed that the constructor was still being called when I expected it to, and the props it's receiving are correct.  However, I added a `console.log(foo)` inside of `renderInnerSpan`, and it looks like the value is true all the time, even after re-rendering the component with its `foo` prop explicitly set to `false`.

It looks like `renderInnerSpan` is only be bound once, and Enzyme is re-using this for every single test.  So, what gives?  I'm re-creating my component in the test, which is calling its constructor with the values I expect - why is my bound `renderInnerSpan` function continuing to use old values?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that **a function cannot be bound multiple times**, as you are trying to in your test case.

The reason for that is that the context is not simply a property of the function itself. When a function is bound, it is rather wrapped in a [bound function exotic object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects).

The context (`this`-assignment) is saved in the `[[BoundThis]]` property of the exotic object. The bound function will always be called with this context, even if it is bound again.

---

You can test this yourself:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this.bar);
}

foo(); // undefined

foo = foo.bind({bar: 1});
foo(); // 1

foo = foo.bind({bar: 2});
foo(); // 1
```

---

**To solve this issue, I suggest you remove the dependency to the context from the rendering function and transfer all required input via function parameters instead:**

```
function renderInnerSpan(foo) {
    if (foo) {
        return <span>Foo is truthy!</span>;
    }

    return <span>Foo is falsy!</span>;
}

export default class extends React.Component {   
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {renderInnerSpan(this.props.foo)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This removes a hidden dependency and makes the code more readable and maintainable. If you ever decide to move the rendering function to its own module, you can now easily do so.

Since you do not need to bind the function context in the constructor anymore, you can even transform your React component into a [stateless function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions):

```
import renderInnerSpan from './renderInnerSpan'

export default (props) => (
    <div>
        {renderInnerSpan(props.foo)}
    </div>
);
```

So much nicer and more readable! :-)

Comment: Stateless functional components seem like the way to go here.  I ended up taking a slightly different approach, and turned my `renderInnerSpan` into a SFC instead.  Thanks for the explanation, this is making more sense now.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me that you defined the *renderInnerSpan* function outside your class and that might create some problems.

Try this:

```
import React from 'react';


export default class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderInnerSpan.bind(this)}
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderInnerSpan() {
    const {foo} = this.props;

    if (foo) {
      return <span>Foo is truthy!</span>;
    }

    return <span>Foo is falsy!</span>;
  }
}
```

Another thing is that your renderComponent function could be rewritten like this:

```
function renderComponent(expectedProps) {
    const componentElement = React.createElement(Test, expectedProps);

    return shallow(componentElement);
}
```

And if you are changing the props in each test, then there is no reason to set the props in a beforeEach block. Just use the new renderComponent in each test instead.

```
it('should display the correct message for truthy values', () => {
    renderedElement = renderComponent({foo: true});
    const span = renderedElement.props().children;

    expect(span.props.children).to.equal('Foo is truthy!');
});
```

Comment: There's no reason why `renderInnerSpan` can't be defined outside the context of the class.  Like I said in the original post, the original implementation **works**.

Comment: Just because you can does not mean you should. The renderInnerSpan belongs to the context of the class and should be defined inside the class.

Comment: This would make the function publicly accessible, which I'm very much against.  Its current location makes the function private, which is important when testing component behavior.